# Trying to assign a set of characters to a string

Tags: c, string, char

I am trying to store a set of A's and B's in a particular order into a string, but couldn't.

```
char String[100];
char choc_type;    
int F=0,L,i,j,choc_num,N; //F=First, L=Last
scanf("%d",&N);
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{              //choc_type is 'A' or 'B' and choc_num is no.of A's or B's        
    scanf("%d %c",&choc_num,&choc_type);
    L=F+choc_num;
    for(j=F;j<L;j++)
    {
        if(choc_type=='A')
        String[j]='A';          //is this a right way to assign character
        else if(choc_type=='B')
        String[j]='B';
     }
     F=L;
     L=L+choc_num;
 } 
printf("%s",String);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: `scanf("%d %c",&choc_num,choc_type);`-->`scanf("%d %c",&choc_num, &choc_type);`.

Comment: input: 1 A, 3 B, 2 A     output : ABBBAA

Comment: Naming a variable "String" doesn't make iit one.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the address of `choc_type` to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%d %c",&choc_num, &choc_type);
                         ^
```

In `C`, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `'\0'` and you are **not** adding null character in `String` array after filling it. After the outer `for` loop, you should do:

```
String[F] = '\0';
```

There is scope of improvement in your code like, you should do some validation of input given by user, check the `scanf()` return value etc.